# Why is L-lysine only sold as L-lysine HCl and not as base (cf. L-arginine)?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base

Both L-lysine and L-arginine enjoy popularity as supplements, but only the latter is sold either as HCl or as base. Given that L-arginine is even more basic than L-lysine (pH 12.5 vs 10.5), that is surprising! Is there a reason why? And could I isolate L-lysine base from L-lysine HCl with a simple reaction? I am thinking of mixing it with sodium bicarbonate, but then I have to remove the NaCl.

Comment: Lysine hydrochloride is an easily handled, stable and well-behaved solid. Lysine freebase is not, it is a sticky oil.

Comment: Interesting! I had just thought that the problem might have been the opposite. If lysine freebase were too powdery, then it could be dangerous to the lungs.